# How can we encrypt/decrypt AES-GCM (A256GCM) algorithm (i.e. JCA: AES/GCM/NoPadding) in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, crypto

I am currently working on a requirement where I am developing Apex REST callouts to an external data providers. Here the complexity lies within the encryption/decryption methods that they are using: Java 8 libraries.

Are there any ways we can encrypt/decrypt the request/response using their AES-GCM (A256GCM) algorithm (i.e. JCA: AES/GCM/NoPadding) in our Apex? I have tried our [Apex Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class) methods, but that didn't really helped. If anyone have done/know something like this, can I get some insights of how to do it? Any references, articles or examples would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this in Apex.

[`Crypto`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) is documented to use only CBC mode:

> These algorithms are all industry standard Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithms with different size keys. They use cipher block chaining (CBC) and PKCS5 padding.

Even though Apex does support AES-256, you won't be able to do any reasonable implementation of GCM mode in pure Apex, and it's not supported by the standard library. You might look at a connector on Heroku or something to decrypt the remote data and provide it in a format Apex can handle.